# SQL Query difference of count

Tags: sql, count

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPlNo.png

I am trying to perform the following query: 
For question number 42, all its answers, sorted so the highest-voted answer is first.

However, my query gives me an error, saying "invalid input syntax for integer: "u"

I have triple checked my database table and it is a character for vote_choice. I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried LIKE as well, but did not solve anything. 
Any suggestions?

```
SELECT answers,
    ((SELECT COUNT(vote_choice) 
    FROM vote 
    JOIN answervote USING (vote_id)
    NATURAL JOIN answers
    WHERE vote_choice = 'u' 
    &  vote.vote_id = answervote.vote_id 
    & answervote.answer_id = answer.answer_id)
  -(SELECT COUNT(vote_choice) 
    FROM vote 
    JOIN answervote USING (vote_id)
    JOIN answers USING (answer_id)
    WHERE vote_choice = 'd'
    &  vote.vote_id = answervote.vote_id 
    & answervote.answer_id = answer.answer_id)) AS total_points
FROM answers
JOIN questions USING (question_id)
WHERE question_id = 42
ORDER BY total_points DESC;
```

Comment: What happens if you don't do the difference and you just output the result of each count?

Comment: Still the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zenksor, try replacing '&' character for the 'AND' operator.

['&' is the bitwise 'AND'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) in T-SQL. It might have the same meaning in other RDBMS. I have never seen & as a relational AND operator.